# Umbraco 7 Search

Tags: search, umbraco7

I have tried a few options for implementing search in Umbraco but none seems to be easy and working.
It would be great help if anybody can give some code help or some precise document for setting it up correctly.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Including snippets of code that you have tried to use can be helpful to answerers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an out-of-the-box library that enables website frontend search for Umbraco 10+, try [USiteSearch](https://www.yart.com.au/blog/usitesearch/)

Note: I am the creator of this package

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the following links:

http://24days.in/umbraco/2013/getting-started-with-examine/

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Searching/Examine/

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/9/16/examining-examine

These should have you up and running in no time. Any issues update the post. ;)